# SQL Server consulta SQL com COUNT e INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma página em PHP onde tenho que retornar dados de duas tabelas que estão em um banco de dados **SQL Server**.

Um dos bancos é de vendedores cadastrados e o outro é das categorias onde eles estão cadastrados. Preciso fazer uma comparação e verificar quantos vendedores estão cadastrados por categoria.

Fiz a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT Vendedor.IdCanal, Count(Vendedor.IdCanal) total, CanalVenda.Nome FROM Vendedor INNER JOIN CanalVenda On Vendedor.IdCanal=CanalVenda.Id GROUP BY Vendedor.IdCanal
```

O problema acontece que essa consulta não me retorna o campo onde tem o **nome** da Categoria. Quando eu a acrescento na pesquisa, retorna o seguinte erro:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Column 'CanalVenda.Nome' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Como retornar corretamente resultados do campo `Nome`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tem de agrupar por aquele campo também.

```
SELECT Vendedor.IdCanal, Count(Vendedor.IdCanal) total, 
CanalVenda.Nome FROM      Vendedor INNER JOIN CanalVenda 
On Vendedor.IdCanal=CanalVenda.Id GROUP BY Vendedor.IdCanal, 
CanalVenda.Nome
```

Comment: Obrigado @reginaldo-rigo, funcionou perfeitamente. ERa isso mesmo, precisava colocar o `CanalVenda.Nome` no Group By. Muito obrigado.